# querySelectorAll - How to only get elements within a certain div

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to limit this selector, to give me result only from inside a div with id "divId1"

```
var polys = document.querySelectorAll('polygon,polyline');
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the space operator:

```
var polys = document.querySelectorAll('#divId1 polygon, #divId1 polyline');
```

[See MDN's page on selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships) to learn more.

Answer (score 11):

You can call querySelectorAll on the div element instead of the document.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll

Sample:

```
var polys = document.getElementById('divId1').querySelectorAll('polygon,polyline');
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#divId1');
var polys = el.querySelectorAll('polygon,polyline');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 4):

```
var polys = document.querySelectorAll('#divId1 polygon, #divId1 polyline');
```